# Xamarin HttpClient GetStringAsync seems inconsistent

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm pulling my hair out on this.

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms project and Prism.  I have this function that calls Google Map Autocomplete.  This past few days it work, but now it doesn't.  I traced it and found that my GetStringAsync is not returning anything.  It just stop at that function, no errors thrown.

This is my code.

```
public async Task<List<PredictionsItem>> Predict(string address)
    {
        List<PredictionsItem> predictions = new List<PredictionsItem>();

        try
        {
            if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                string _url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" + address +"&types=geocode&components=country:ph&key=" + Key;

                string response = await client.GetStringAsync(_url);

                client.Dispose();

                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);
                return result.predictions;
            }
            return predictions;
        }
        catch
        {
            return predictions;
        }
    }
```

It just stops here "string response = await client.GetStringAsync(_url);".  No errors thrown.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: yes.  I have a valid API key.  It worked a few hours ago, then without changing anything, it stopped working.  Same thing yesterday.

Comment: Sounds like you might be getting rate limited on that IP, check the `logcat` output for the warning/errors.

Comment: Did you change how you call `Predict()`? If you are blocking maybe it is causing a deadlock, though I don't know anything about Xamarin and if it uses a synchronization context or not.

Comment: Crowcoder, List<PredictionsItem> predictionsItems = await locationServices.Predict(address);

Comment: SushiHangover , interesting.  But when I paste the URL on the browser, it actually works as expected.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the direct call, anything up the call chain can cause a deadlock if it isn't async all the way.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I found the culprit.  It was my internet connection.  Though it seems I'm connected to the internet, it takes a lot of time to return and in fact I observed it is timing out.  Now I'm looking how slow httpclient are.

Comment: @JohnMombay If have solved this , remember to share the experience in answer :-)